# Rails5 how to refactor a find_or_create_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I got some old code I'm trying to port over to Rails 5 (reasons)

And I ran into this....

```
  def vol_event_for_date(date)
    VolunteerEvent.find_or_create_by_description_and_date("Roster ##{self.id}", date)
  end

  def vol_event_for_weekday(wday)
    VolunteerDefaultEvent.find_or_create_by_description_and_weekday_id("Roster ##{self.id}", wday)
  end
```

I know from a post I've seen on S.O. that the find_by thingie is an old outdated Rails helper of some kind so my question is...how can I refactor this for a Rails 5.0.7 app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change is actually very simple as explained in the [Rails 4 Active Record Deprecations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations)

> `find_or_create_by_...` can be rewritten using `find_or_create_by(...)`.

```
VolunteerEvent.find_or_create_by_description_and_date("Roster ##{self.id}", date)
```

just changes to

```
VolunteerEvent.find_or_create_by(description: "Roster ##{self.id}", date: date)
```